# J2EE - JPA - EJB3 - Transactions in MDB methods

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jboss5.x, jta, jboss-mdb

I have resource local datasource (Oracle9i) deployed at JBoss 5.1.0:

```
<datasources>
  <local-tx-datasource>
    <jndi-name>OracleDS</jndi-name>
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP_ADDRESS:1521:inv9i</connection-url>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    <user-name>***</user-name>
    <password>***</password>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
    <metadata>
        <type-mapping>Oracle9i</type-mapping>
    </metadata>
  </local-tx-datasource>
</datasources>
```

persistence unit:

```
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="myEJB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>java:OracleDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <class>hr.bel.model.Instrument</class>
        <class>hr.bel.model.Order</class>
        <class>hr.bel.model.OrderAdditionalData</class>
        <class>hr.bel.model.OrderCondition</class>
        <class>hr.bel.model.Trade</class>
        <class>hr.bel.model.TradeAdditionalData</class>
        <class>hr.bel.model.Tradeticker</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Within an MDB, when onMessage method is invoked I'm trying to persist an bean and fetch latest 5 beans of that type via an namedQuery:

```
@PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em = null;
    public void onMessage(MyMessage msg) {
        Map message = msg.getMessageTree(false);
        Instrument instrument = em.find(Instrument.class, 55);      

        Tradeticker tt = createTradeticker(message);
        tt.setInstrument(instrument);

        log.info("Persisting tradeticker: " + tt.getTradeType());               
        em.persist(tt);             
        log.info("Tradeticker persisted...");

        List<Tradeticker> last5 = em.createNamedQuery("getLast5").setParameter(1,instrument.getInstrumentId()).setMaxResults(5).getResultList();
        log.info("Persisted tradetickers size: " + last5.size());
    }
```

My problem is that there is no any trace of an error but still there is no any persisted objects in my Oracle database. After great number of messages call `last5.size()` returns 0. Log is perfectly clean.

Only restrictions for MDBs I found are I have to use REQUIRED or NOT_SUPPORTED transaction attribute on methods. My onMessage is not annotated so it uses REQUIRED as default. Also I have no any annotations on MDB class so bean should use container managed transaction.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you manage the transaction yourself when working with a non-jta data source?  That is, get a transaction and commit the data yourself?  I leave that kind of stuff to JTA myself, but when I read [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Transactions) correctly it looks like in your case you need to commit explicitely.

Comment: Yes, you're right! I figure that later... What was new to me is that if I manage my own transaction I'm not allowed to use injected EM but one obtained via JNDI lookup call. Obviously I should read more detailed about ejb3.

Comment: `Shouldn't you manage the transaction yourself when working with a non-jta data source?` Actually, the OP would have to commit explicitly because he's using a *resource-local* entity manager, not because of the `non-jta-datasource` (which is not really appropriate though since MDB + JPA would require a global transaction).

Answer (score 2):

OK. This is how I solved problem, 1st define tx datasource, 2nd define jta model and jta-datasource in persistence.xml.

New datasource definition:

```
<datasources>
  <xa-datasource>
    <jndi-name>OracleDS</jndi-name>
    <isSameRM-override-value>false</isSameRM-override-value>
    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:oracle:thin:@IP_ADDRESS:1521:inv9i</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="User">***</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="Password">***</xa-datasource-property>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
    <no-tx-separate-pools/>
    <metadata>
      <type-mapping>Oracle9i</type-mapping>
    </metadata>
  </xa-datasource>
```

jboss:service=TransactionManager

new persistence.xml:

```
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="myEJB" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:OracleDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>hr.bel.model.Instrument</class>
        <class>hr.bel.model.Order</class>
        <class>hr.bel.model.OrderAdditionalData</class>
        <class>hr.bel.model.OrderCondition</class>
        <class>hr.bel.model.Trade</class>
        <class>hr.bel.model.TradeAdditionalData</class>
        <class>hr.bel.model.Tradeticker</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9iDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

My java code is same and now I'm getting my object persisted! After discussion with my colleagues who use mysql dbms we figure that Oracle with its tx and no-tx datasources made strict restrictions on how and where datasources will be used.
Thank you all!

Comment: Yes, since you want the Entity Manager to be injected, you must use a container-manager entity manager (which must be a `JTA` entity manager) and supply a `jta-data-source`.

Answer (score 0):

In passing: a common pattern is to put the business logic into a SLSB and call that from your MDB - allows for other use of the logic. Should make no difference to your problem though.

I would expect the default transaction attribute to be Requried. I don't see a reason why this should fail.

I would do these things:

1). Put a try/catch around the business logic. Are any exceptions thrown?

2). Remove the query, I can't see why it should be failing, but lets remove any possibility taht it might be interfering with the insertion. Let's rely on the database. Use a command-line SQL statement or other utility to see what's in the DB after a few messages have gone through.

3). Check the logs again, is an error appearing anywhere?

Comment: after changing descriptors as I explained in my solution all works fine. Anyway regarding putting business logic into a SLSB I skip that because there was important performance requirement by customer. How SLSB-s would be used just from MDBS I skiped them avoiding all proxy logic around them. It would be nice if there is some good link/literature about performance issues when running ejbs.